# PHP script doesn't reach end - query execution time too long?

Tags: php, sql, timeout

A PHP page of our web application has a rather complex query. On the production website this takes about 20 seconds to complete, and then the results are displayed. I have a test version of the site running on my local desktop. When I run the (Postgres) query directly in PGAdmin, it takes about 3 minutes to complete.

So my desktop is slow - not a real problem now. PHP does however quit loading the page and displays no results. Plain text that should be displayed right after the results is not shown either. Searching for solutions I found I could set the max_execution time for PHP on the page itself. I did so using the following code at the first line of the page:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

This doesn't make a difference. The page loading stops after 6 seconds. What can I do to display the results?

Comment: take a look at the apache error_log!

Comment: Why does the query take so long, surely even if you fix the timeout issue, users will have given up waiting

Comment: use query explain.. to find out problems

Comment: @niyou: thanks, should have thought about that myself. It turned out to be the memory limit. It works now and strangely enough it works twice as fast like this. You can make this an answer if you want the points.

Comment: @user574632: this is a backend page, only used by admins who know it takes a long time, and on production it takes about 20 seconds, not a real problem I think.

Comment: I've set the memory limit locally to 2048MB, and now it takes 15 seconds, similar to the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Use [set_time_limit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

You should read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) for this function where it says:Warning: This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini.

So make sure your PHP isn't running in safe-mode, else there wont be any way to set or modify the script execution time.